# cudaMalloc setting errno despite returning cudaSuccess

Tags: c++, cuda, runtime-error, gpu

Currently for some reason cudaMalloc is setting errno to 17, despite returning a cudaSuccess. I have been scouring the internet but my google foo has not brought any enlightenment to me, so I have decided to ask the stack overflow people.

Here is my output

```
ERROR: What is not going down, ERRSTR: Success, ERRNO 0
ERROR: What is going on here?, ERRSTR: File exists, ERRNO 17
```

And here is my code (some of it at least)

```
//headers
#define CheckError(MESSAGE) do { fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: %s, ERRSTR: %s, ERRNO %i\n",MESSAGE,strerror(errno),errno); } while(0);
#define CudaSafeCall( err ) __cudaSafeCall( err, __FILE__, __LINE__ )
#define ARRAY_LENGTH ( 1000000 )
#define ARRAY_ELEMENT_SIZE ( sizeof(int) )
#define ARRAY_SIZE ( (size_t)ARRAY_ELEMENT_SIZE * ARRAY_LENGTH )

inline void __cudaSafeCall( cudaError err, const char *file, const int line )
{
    if ( cudaSuccess != err )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "cudaSafeCall() failed at %s:%i : %s\n",
             file, line, cudaGetErrorString( err ) );
        exit( -1 );
    }
    return;
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    ..... Other Code ......

    int *device_array;
    CheckError("What is not going on here.");
    CudaSafeCall(cudaMalloc((void**)&device_array,ARRAY_SIZE));
    CheckError("What is going on here?");

    ..... Other Code ......
}
```

Does anyone have anyidea what might be going on here? Right now the ARRAY_SIZE is set to 4 Million, but the same issue shows up when it is 400.

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from CUDA? For me, it looks like the error is coming from the C++ (host) side and has nothing to do with the CUDA-Runtime, since the CUDA-Runtime will give you a cudaError.

Comment: I am not sure where the error is coming from if not from cuda. I don't know too much about how errno works but what else could cause it to be set? Could other processes be the cause?

Comment: I am quite sure, that the error is not coming from the CUDA-Runtime (though it might be caused by CUDA).

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted. It's not immediately intuitive that a successful function could set errno to a nonzero value. It prompted a concise and insightful answer (I ran into this calling cudaMallocPitch and one of my unit tests was looking at errno for another reason).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be assuming that `errno` must be zero if the previous function returned no error.

This is not the case.

`errno` is not required to be set to zero if a previous function is successful.

From the [linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html):

> > Its value is significant only when the return value of the call indicated an error

and

> > a function that succeeds is allowed to change errno.

In your case, the previous function (whatever it was, in this case probably `cudaMalloc` or some system function called by `cudaMalloc` library routine) was successful.  Therefore the contents of the `errno` variable are not significant.